# Can I use different GPU for video games?

Tags: graphics-cards

My computer have actually a 1060 3GB. I would like to get a new GPU for video games purposes but I would like to keep my 1060 in the build so its not a waste.

So what I was thinking is buying a more recent GPU and mother board with two slots for video cards and use the 1060 for screens and the new GPU to compute the game graphics.

Is that possible ? And if not, is there others tricks like this possible ?

Comment: Two cards for different jobs - good idea! Maybe different ports (HDMI + DisplayPort) and select source in monitor settings before gaming. I suppose modern Operation System may support automatic run device which is in use right now.  P.S. - I have gtx 760 and smiling when had red about Your upgrade from 1060 :)

Comment: @SergeySerov So what's your saying is I'll have one card for one monitor and the other for the second monitor ? Because what I would like is one card for both monitors and the other to compute. A 1060 for just a website page feel like a waste. P.S. - I was playing League of Legends so my 1060 was overkill but I'm bored of the game and wan't to discover newer expercience, everything depends on which games you play ^^

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for here, what exactly are you planning to use the 1060 for, when your new GPU is in place?

Comment: It's possible, but not really worth the effort. Just sell the 1060.